# How to import an saved Tensorflow model train using tf.estimator and predict on input data

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have save the model using tf.estimator .method export_savedmodel as follows:

```
export_dir="exportModel/"

feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns)

input_receiver_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec)

classifier.export_savedmodel(export_dir, input_receiver_fn, as_text=False, checkpoint_path="Model/model.ckpt-400")
```

How can I import this saved model and use for predictions?

Comment: Can you comment a bit more on the environment in which you want to perform predictions? Do you just want to write a Python app that loads the model in the same process and performs prediction? Do you want to run your own production-grade service for serving your model? Do you want to use a managed service in the cloud?

Comment: Now, I am trying to write a python script to load the model and perform prediction.

Comment: [Example of export_savedmodel function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48329456/4268517)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I tried to search for a good base example, but it appears the documentation and samples are a bit scattered for this topic. So let's start with a base example: the tf.estimator [quickstart](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/estimator).

That particular example doesn't actually export a model, so let's do that (not need for use case 1):

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
  """Build the serving inputs."""
  # The outer dimension (None) allows us to batch up inputs for
  # efficiency. However, it also means that if we want a prediction
  # for a single instance, we'll need to wrap it in an outer list.
  inputs = {"x": tf.placeholder(shape=[None, 4], dtype=tf.float32)}
  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)

export_dir = classifier.export_savedmodel(
    export_dir_base="/path/to/model",
    serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

**Huge asterisk on this code**: there appears to be a bug in TensorFlow 1.3 that doesn't allow you to do the above export on a "canned" estimator (such as DNNClassifier). For a workaround, see the "Appendix: Workaround" section.

The code below references `export_dir` (return value from the export step) to emphasize that it is **not** "/path/to/model", but rather, a subdirectory of that directory whose name is a timestamp.

**Use Case 1: Perform prediction in the same process as training**

This is an sci-kit learn type of experience, and is already exemplified by the sample. For completeness' sake, you simply call `predict` on the trained model:

```
classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=2000)
# [...snip...]
predictions = list(classifier.predict(input_fn=predict_input_fn))
predicted_classes = [p["classes"] for p in predictions]
```

**Use Case 2: Load a SavedModel into Python/Java/C++ and perform predictions**

*Python Client*

Perhaps the easiest thing to use if you want to do prediction in Python is [SavedModelPredictor](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/32ffc5a81eee8c39bbe71536212a773b1ffd4eb2/tensorflow/contrib/predictor/saved_model_predictor.py#L114).  In the Python program that will use the `SavedModel`, we need code like this:

```
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor

predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model(export_dir)
predictions = predict_fn(
    {"x": [[6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5],
           [5.8, 3.1, 5.0, 1.7]]})
print(predictions['scores'])
```

*Java Client*

```
package dummy;

import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.tensorflow.SavedModelBundle;
import org.tensorflow.Session;
import org.tensorflow.Tensor;

public class Client {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Session session = SavedModelBundle.load(args[0], "serve").session();

    Tensor x =
        Tensor.create(
            new long[] {2, 4},
            FloatBuffer.wrap(
                new float[] {
                  6.4f, 3.2f, 4.5f, 1.5f,
                  5.8f, 3.1f, 5.0f, 1.7f
                }));

    // Doesn't look like Java has a good way to convert the
    // input/output name ("x", "scores") to their underlying tensor,
    // so we hard code them ("Placeholder:0", ...).
    // You can inspect them on the command-line with saved_model_cli:
    //
    // $ saved_model_cli show --dir $EXPORT_DIR --tag_set serve --signature_def serving_default
    final String xName = "Placeholder:0";
    final String scoresName = "dnn/head/predictions/probabilities:0";

    List<Tensor> outputs = session.runner()
        .feed(xName, x)
        .fetch(scoresName)
        .run();

    // Outer dimension is batch size; inner dimension is number of classes
    float[][] scores = new float[2][3];
    outputs.get(0).copyTo(scores);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(scores));
  }
}
```

*C++ Client*

You'll likely want to use [`tensorflow::LoadSavedModel`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.h) with [`Session`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/public/session.h#L83).

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#include "tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/public/session.h"

namespace tf = tensorflow;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  const string export_dir = argv[1];

  tf::SavedModelBundle bundle;
  tf::Status load_status = tf::LoadSavedModel(
      tf::SessionOptions(), tf::RunOptions(), export_dir, {"serve"}, &bundle);
  if (!load_status.ok()) {
    std::cout << "Error loading model: " << load_status << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  // We should get the signature out of MetaGraphDef, but that's a bit
  // involved. We'll take a shortcut like we did in the Java example.
  const string x_name = "Placeholder:0";
  const string scores_name = "dnn/head/predictions/probabilities:0";

  auto x = tf::Tensor(tf::DT_FLOAT, tf::TensorShape({2, 4}));
  auto matrix = x.matrix<float>();
  matrix(0, 0) = 6.4;
  matrix(0, 1) = 3.2;
  matrix(0, 2) = 4.5;
  matrix(0, 3) = 1.5;
  matrix(0, 1) = 5.8;
  matrix(0, 2) = 3.1;
  matrix(0, 3) = 5.0;
  matrix(0, 4) = 1.7;

  std::vector<std::pair<string, tf::Tensor>> inputs = {{x_name, x}};
  std::vector<tf::Tensor> outputs;

  tf::Status run_status =
      bundle.session->Run(inputs, {scores_name}, {}, &outputs);
  if (!run_status.ok()) {
    cout << "Error running session: " << run_status << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  for (const auto& tensor : outputs) {
    std::cout << tensor.matrix<float>() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

**Use Case 3: Serve a model using TensorFlow Serving**

Exporting models in a manner amenable to serving a [Classification model](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/apis/classification.proto) requires that the input be a `tf.Example` object. Here's how we might export a model for TensorFlow serving:

```
def serving_input_receiver_fn():
  """Build the serving inputs."""
  # The outer dimension (None) allows us to batch up inputs for
  # efficiency. However, it also means that if we want a prediction
  # for a single instance, we'll need to wrap it in an outer list.
  example_bytestring = tf.placeholder(
      shape=[None],
      dtype=tf.string,
  )
  features = tf.parse_example(
      example_bytestring,
      tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns)
  )
  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(
      features, {'examples': example_bytestring})

export_dir = classifier.export_savedmodel(
    export_dir_base="/path/to/model",
    serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

The reader is referred to TensorFlow Serving's documentation for more instructions on how to setup TensorFlow Serving, so I'll only provide the client code here:

```
  # Omitting a bunch of connection/initialization code...
  # But at some point we end up with a stub whose lifecycle
  # is generally longer than that of a single request.
  stub = create_stub(...)

  # The actual values for prediction. We have two examples in this
  # case, each consisting of a single, multi-dimensional feature `x`.
  # This data here is the equivalent of the map passed to the 
  # `predict_fn` in use case #2.
  examples = [
    tf.train.Example(
      features=tf.train.Features(
        feature={"x": tf.train.Feature(
          float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5]))})),
    tf.train.Example(
      features=tf.train.Features(
        feature={"x": tf.train.Feature(
          float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[5.8, 3.1, 5.0, 1.7]))})),
  ]

  # Build the RPC request.
  predict_request = predict_pb2.PredictRequest()
  predict_request.model_spec.name = "default"
  predict_request.inputs["examples"].CopyFrom(
      tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(examples, tf.float32))

  # Perform the actual prediction.
  stub.Predict(request, PREDICT_DEADLINE_SECS)
```

Note that the key, `examples`, that is referenced in the `predict_request.inputs` needs to match the key used in the `serving_input_receiver_fn` at export time (cf. the constructor to `ServingInputReceiver` in that code).

**Appendix: Working around Exports from Canned Models in TF 1.3**

There appears to be a bug in TensorFlow 1.3 in which canned models do not export properly for use case 2 (the problem does not exist for "custom" estimators). Here's is a workaround that wraps a DNNClassifier to make things work, specifically for the Iris example:

```
# Build 3 layer DNN with 10, 20, 10 units respectively.
class Wrapper(tf.estimator.Estimator):
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    dnn = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(**kwargs)

    def model_fn(mode, features, labels):
      spec = dnn._call_model_fn(features, labels, mode)
      export_outputs = None
      if spec.export_outputs:
        export_outputs = {
           "serving_default": tf.estimator.export.PredictOutput(
                  {"scores": spec.export_outputs["serving_default"].scores,
                   "classes": spec.export_outputs["serving_default"].classes})}

      # Replace the 3rd argument (export_outputs)
      copy = list(spec)
      copy[4] = export_outputs
      return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, *copy)

    super(Wrapper, self).__init__(model_fn, kwargs["model_dir"], dnn.config)

classifier = Wrapper(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                     hidden_units=[10, 20, 10],
                     n_classes=3,
                     model_dir="/tmp/iris_model")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the details explanation. I am able to get the scores for each classes using print(predictions['scores']) and print(predictions['classes']) . can we able to get the predicted class.

Comment: @nayan The output of DNNClassifier is designed to support a very large output space where you might want predict the top-n classes. The idea is that the `classes` key contains the names of the classes corresponding to the scores in the `scores` output. However, I don't believe you actually can do top-n, yet. So what you get in `classes` is just the list of classes, in order, repeated for every output.

To get the predicted class, you have two options: (1) write a custom estimator (possibly wrapping DNNClassifier or similar to do the hard work) (2) have the client take the argmax of `scores`

Comment: Thanks. I am able to get the top 1 predict class using argmax of scores. If there is an equivalent  c/c++ api for  python predictor function as in Use Case 2, So that it can be integrated to iOS/android platform.

Comment: Thanks. i am able to run the java and c++ client on PC. when i tried  to integrate the java code on android got following error                                                
                                                                 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Loading a SavedModel is not supported in Android. File a bug at https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues if this feature is important to you at org.tensorflow.SavedModelBundle.load(Native Method)

Comment: I have tried to freeze the model with python script freeze_graph.py                      python tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py --input_graph model/graph.pbtxt --input_checkpoint model/model.ckpt-3000 --output_node_names=dnn/head/predictions/probabilities .                                 get following error message                                                            
TypeError: names_to_saveables must be a dict mapping string names to Tensors/Variables. Not a variable: Tensor("dnn/hiddenlayer_0/bias:0", shape=(5,), dtype=float32).      Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using --input_saved_model_dir instead of --input_{graph_model,checkpoint}? This question probably deserves its own question/answer on stack overflow.

Comment: Thanks. --input_save_model_dir option is working and  able to freeze the model. By mistake i was using old source code folder for tensor-flow and --input_save_model_dir option was not available there.

Comment: @rhaertel80 How can I convert a `SavedModel` to `.pb` format. The `SavedModel` was exported using `estimator.export_savedmodel`, I can load this predictor using `tf.contrib.predictor.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)`.

Comment: Do I still need such workaround in TF > 1.3, esp. TF 1.10? Has it been solved in newer version TF?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it was addressed in TF 1.4, but it looks like the getting started link has changed and I can't easily find the model that this post was based on. Maybe you can try out your code and if there are problems start a new thread (feel free to bring said thread to my attention).

Comment: @rhaertel80 when I export the serving input function using `tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features,feature_placeholders)`and saving that input function using `estimator.export_savedmodel(export_dir, csv_serving_input_fn_vtwo)` I got the following error **ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)**

Comment: The example in my answer above uses (features, features). So you're doing something a bit different. Make sure the type of both `features` and `feature_placeholders` is a dict. If you are still having problems, considering creating a new question.

Comment: I tried your method and got "ValueError: Got signature_def_key "serving_default". Available signatures are ['predict']. Original error:
No SignatureDef with key 'serving_default' found in MetaGraphDef." error.

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul That might warrant it's own question. It would be helpful to note what version of TF you are using.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think there is a bug with canned Estimators (or rather if there was ever one, it has been fixed). I was able to successfully export a canned estimator model using Python and import it in Java.

Here is my code to export the model:

```
a = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("a");
b = tf.feature_column.numeric_column("b");
feature_columns = [a, b];

model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns ...);

# To export
feature_spec = tf.feature_column.make_parse_example_spec(feature_columns);
export_input_fn = tf.estimator.export.build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec);
servable_model_path = model.export_savedmodel(servable_model_dir, export_input_fn, as_text=True);
```

To import the model in Java, I used the Java client code provided by rhaertel80 above and it works. Hope this also answers Ben Fowler's question above.

Comment: Could you add the Java side of the prediction to this answer, please? Mainly to see how you are preparing the input for build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn in Java.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the TensorFlow team does not agree that there is a bug in version 1.3 using canned estimators for exporting a model under use case #2. I submitted a bug report here: 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13477

The response I received from TensorFlow is that the input must only be a single string tensor. It appears that there may be a way to consolidate multiple features into a single string tensor using serialized TF.examples, but I have not found a clear method to do this. If anyone has code showing how to do this, I would be appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

You need to export the saved model using  tf.contrib.export_savedmodel and you need to define input receiver function to pass input to.
  Later you can load the saved model ( generally saved.model.pb) from the disk and serve it.

[TensorFlow: How to predict from a SavedModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45900653/tensorflow-how-to-predict-from-a-savedmodel/47645229#47645229)