# Tensorflow: Layer size dependent on batch size?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I am currently trying to get familiar with the Tensorflow library and I have a rather fundamental question that bugs me.

While building a convolutional neural network for MNIST classification I tried to use my own model_fn. In which usually the following line occurs to reshape the input features.

`x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1])`, with the -1 referring to the input batch size.

Since I use this node as input to my convolutional layer,

```py
x = tf.reshape(x, shape=[-1, 28, 28, 1]) 
conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 32, 5, activation=tf.nn.relu)
```

does this mean that the size all my networks layers are dependent on the batch size?

I tried freezing and running the graph on a single test input, which will only work if I provide n=batch_size test images.

Can you give me a hint on how to make my network run on any input batchsize while predicting? 
Also I guess using the tf.reshape node (*see first node in cnn_layout*) in the network definition is not the best input for serving.

I will append my network layer-up and the model_fn

```py
def cnn_layout(features,reuse,is_training):
 with tf.variable_scope('cnn',reuse=reuse):
    # resize input to [batchsize,height,width,channel]
    x = tf.reshape(features['x'], shape=[-1,30,30,1], name='input_placeholder')
    # conv1, 32 filter, 5 kernel
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, 32, 5, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv1')
    # pool1, 2 stride, 2 kernel
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv1, 2, 2, name='pool1')
    # conv2, 64 filter, 3 kernel
    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(pool1, 64, 3, activation=tf.nn.relu, name='conv2')
    # pool2, 2 stride, 2 kernel
    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv2, 2, 2, name='pool2')
    # flatten pool2
    flatten = tf.contrib.layers.flatten(pool2)
    # fc1 with 1024 neurons
    fc1 = tf.layers.dense(flatten, 1024, name='fc1')
    # 75% dropout
    drop = tf.layers.dropout(fc1, rate=0.75, training=is_training, name='dropout')
    # output logits
    output = tf.layers.dense(drop, 1, name='output_logits')
    return output


def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    # setup two networks one for training one for prediction while sharing weights
    logits_train = cnn_layout(features=features,reuse=False,is_training=True)
    logits_test = cnn_layout(features=features,reuse=True,is_training=False)

    # predictions
    predictions = tf.round(tf.sigmoid(logits_test),name='predictions')
    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.PREDICT:
        return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(mode, predictions=predictions)

    # define loss and optimizer
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits_train,labels=labels),name='loss')
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE, name='optimizer')
    train = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_global_step(),name='train')

    # accuracy for evaluation
    accuracy = tf.metrics.accuracy(labels=labels,predictions=predictions,name='accuracy')

    # summarys for tensorboard
    tf.summary.scalar('loss',loss)

    # return training and evalution spec
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        predictions=predictions,
        loss=loss,
        train_op=train,
        eval_metric_ops={'accuracy':accuracy}
    )
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just want to briefly provide my found solution. Since I did not want to build a scalable production grade model, but a simple model runner in python to execute my CNN locally.

To export the model I used,

```py
input_size = 900

def serving_input_receiver_fn():
    inputs = {"x": tf.placeholder(shape=[None, input_size], dtype=tf.float32)}
    return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(inputs, inputs)

model.export_savedmodel(
    export_dir_base=model_dir,
    serving_input_receiver_fn=serving_input_receiver_fn)
```

To load and run it (without needing the model definition again) I used the tensorflow predictor class.

```py
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor

class TFRunner:
    """ runs a frozen cnn graph """
    def __init__(self,model_dir):
        self.predictor = predictor.from_saved_model(model_dir)

    def run(self, input_list):
        """ runs the input list through the graph, returns output """
        if len(input_list) > 1:
            inputs = np.vstack(input_list)
            predictions = self.predictor({"x": inputs})
        elif len(input_list) == 1:
            predictions = self.predictor({"x": input_list[0]})
        else:
            predictions = []
        return predictions
```

Answer (score 1):

In the typical scenario, the rank of `features['x']` is already going to be 4, with the outer dimension being *the actual batch size*, so there's no need to resize it.

Let me try to explain.

You haven't shown your `serving_input_receiver_fn` yet and there are several ways to do that, although in the end the principle is similar across them all. If you're using TensorFlow Serving, then you probably use `build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn`. It's informative to look at the source code:

```
def build_parsing_serving_input_receiver_fn(feature_spec,
                                            default_batch_size=None):    
  serialized_tf_example = array_ops.placeholder(
      dtype=dtypes.string,
      shape=[default_batch_size],                                      
      name='input_example_tensor')
  receiver_tensors = {'examples': serialized_tf_example}
  features = parsing_ops.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_spec)
  return ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)
```

So in your client, you're going to prepare a request that has one or more `Example`s in it (let's say the length is `N`). The server treats the serialized examples as a list of strings which get "fed" into the `input_example_tensor` placeholder. The shape (which is `None`) dynamically gets filled in to be the size of the list (`N`).

Then the `parse_example` op parses each item in the placeholder and out pops a Tensor for each feature whose outer dimension is `N`. In your case, you'll have `x` with shape=[N, 30, 30, 1].

(Note that other serving systems, such as CloudML Engine, do not operate on `Example` objects, but the principles are the same).

Comment: I didn't use a serving_input_receiver but I froze the graph by using `graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants()` and then calling `with tf.gfile.GFile(output_path, "wb") as f: f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())`. But I guess this also freezes the minibatch size into the graph.

So just to be clear. I will need a kind of serving server backend instead of the standart tensorflow lib to execute a trained model ? Since my model is really small and should execute very fast I am looking for a rather lean solution.

Comment: I'm not sure whether or not freezing the graph freezes the batch size into graph; off hand, I'd say it should not. Note that you can execute a trained model relatively simply without a server backend. I'd recommend exporting your model as a SavedModel (you can still freeze your graph). That gives you better portability and arguably better libraries for inference (plus the option of easily graduating to a more advanced serving solution if necessary at a later date). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46139198/1399222 for how to do prediction with a SavedModel.

Comment: If you don't want to use SavedModel, the basic idea is to use `tensorflow.python.training.saver.import_meta_graph` then you can use `session.Run` to feed the inputs and fetch the outputs. The trick is getting the correct names of the input and output tensors.

Comment: The provided thread did really help me with my problem. Prediction is also quite a lot faster now. It wasn't my goal to build a production grade serving but a to find a simple way to run my network locally. Thank you nevertheless.

Comment: Glad to hear it!