# Tensorflow Estimator: using predict() function in separate script

Tags: python, validation, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I have successfully (I hope) trained and evaluated a model using the tf.Estimator where I reach a train/eval accuracy of around 83-85%. So now, I would like to test my model on a separate dataset using the predict() function call in the Estimator class. Preferably I would like to do this in a separate script.

I've at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098863/how-to-import-an-saved-tensorflow-model-train-using-tf-estimator-and-predict-on) which says that I need to export as a SavedModel, but is this really necessary? Looking at the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.3/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#__init__) for the Estimator class, it seems like I can just pass the path to my checkpoint and graph files via the `model_dir` parameter. Has anyone any experience with this? When I run my model on the same dataset I used for validation, I do not obtain the same performance as during the validation phase... :-(

Comment: Passing the same path used for training to the Estimator constructor and then calling predict() should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need a separate file containing your `model_fn` definition. Than you instantiate the same estimator class in another script, using the same `model_fn` definition and the same `model_dir`.

That works because the Estimator API recovers the `tf.Graph` definitions and the latest `model.ckpt` files by itself so you are able to continue training, evaluation and prediction.

Comment: I found out that the reason my predict() function didn't work as expected was because when I wrote the script for gathering data in TFRecords format, I hadn't noticed that os.listdir lists directory elements in random order, so the predicted labels didn't match up with the ground truth at all.

Your comment is correct.