# Q: Tensorflow estimator does not reinitialize correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've built and trained a classifier using a custom estimator. As I need to use it on a separate dataset afterwards I've got my model_fn in a separate file. Training and evaluating my dataset straight away as follows (with input_fn shortened for readability)

```
# Instantiate the estimator
birdsclassifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(
    model_fn=cnn_model, model_dir=model_path)
tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(
          tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=50)

# Train the model   
def input_fn():
    #Training dataset preparation happens here
    return {'x': features}, labels
birdsclassifier.train(
    input_fn=input_fn,
    steps=num_steps,
    hooks=[logging_hook])
# Evaluate the model and print results
print('begin eval')
def eval_input_fn():
    #Validation dataset preparation happens here
    return {'x': featuresTest}, labelsT

eval_results = birdsclassifier.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
print(eval_results)
```

and gives the following output

```
 {'accuracy': 0.5952381, 'loss': 1.4494723, 'global_step': 2000}
```

however running a script with the evaluation code only (having double checked for shuffling issues and that both the validation datasets are identical) yields

```
{'accuracy': 0.083333336, 'loss': 4.551247, 'global_step': 2000}
```

Since the global step is the same the graph seems to be at least partially correctly reconstructed from checkpoint - however it looks as if the variables were not correctly loaded. Also running the second script repetitively gives me slightly different outputs.
I have also noticed that re-running the training script with small number of steps keeps increasing the global_step count, but also results in an accuracy drop which suggests that the training restarts from random

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783391/tensorflow-estimator-using-predict-function-in-separate-script) as well as [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/13895) suggest that my method should work just fine.

Note: in case the code snippets are insufficient the remainder of the code is here: https://github.com/pbkowalski/cnn_classification_birds