# GCMLE Local Predict in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

Is there any way to perform the equivalent of `gcloud ml-engine local predict --model-dir=$MODEL_DIR --json-instances=$JSON_INSTANCE` within a jupyter notebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me give a quick answer; one that may be updated at some point in the future. Basically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46098863/how-to-import-an-saved-tensorflow-model-train-using-tf-estimator-and-predict-on/46139198#46139198) should apply. For example:

```
import json
from tensorflow.contrib import predictor

def columnarize(instancse):
  out = {}
  for instance in instances:
    for k, v in instance.items():
      out.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
  return out

def mapify(outputs, fetch_tensors):
    return dict(zip(fetch_tensors.iterkeys(), outputs))

def rowify(columns):
  out = []
  num_instances = len(next(columns.itervalues()))
  for row in range(num_instances):
    out.append({
        name: output[row, ...].tolist()
        for name, output in columns.iteritems()
    })
  return out    

instances = [
    {"x": [6.4, 3.2, 4.5, 1.5], "y": -1},
    {"x": [5.8, 3.1, 5.0, 1.7], "y": 5},
]

predict_fn = predictor.from_saved_model(export_dir)
outputs = predict_fn(columnarize(instances))
predictions = rowify(mapify(outputs, predictor._fetch_tensors))
print(predictions)
```

Comment: `rowify()` is the only part that doesn't appear to be working. Basically it seems like you are trying to get the response formatted in the same way the instances went in, correct?

Comment: I added `mapify()`. I think `tensorflow.contrib.predictor` might have a bug, because the docs say it returns a dict, but it doesn't.