# Local prediction of ML Engine model

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, tensorflow-serving, google-cloud-ml

I want to make a **local prediction** on a **saved** model which is trained with the ML Engine. For my CNN Model, I'm using the sample code of the flower dataset (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/flowers).

I have the following files:
[image]

How to restore my model and make a prediction which return a list or dict with the accuracy scores?

I already tried to restore my model but it didn't work out.

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:    
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('saved_model.pb')
    saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('variables/'))
    print(sess.run('w1:0'))
```

Note 1: My goal is to make a classification report or/and confusion matrix just like we have in Keras.

Note 2: My model consists of 87 labels.

Note 3: Already accessed prediction scores with the Online Prediction API of ML Engine.

Comment: Why did restoring your model not work?

Comment: Complete error:
Use the 'bytes' type if you intend to send raw bytes.
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('saved_model.pb')
  File "/Library/Fra***3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1920, in import_meta_graph
    meta_graph_def = meta_graph.read_meta_graph_file(meta_graph_or_file)
  File "/Library****b/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/meta_graph.py", line 643, in read_meta_graph_file
    text_format.Merge(file_content.decode("utf-8"), meta_graph_def)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position 3: invalid start byte

Comment: I think you'll find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46139198/1399222